# How to make my module move an object using value set in UserForm/

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I'm trying to automatize some processes I often do at work. Unfortunately I have no clue about programming so I've been struggling a lot with this.

I have an userform that has a textbox where you're supposed to type in how much you want the object to be moved on X axis. There are multiple objects and I can't wait to experiment how to move them all in proper direction, but the issue is, I can't even move one.

I created a variable, but I can't seem to be able to use it with Object.Move.

Right now VBA tells me to assign the values to an array, so I did that, but I can't put variables into an array apparently.

I've tried simply declaring the variable as public, calling it let's say for example "Value", and using `Object.Move (Value), 0`

or

`Object.Move Value(), 0`

Tried both, because I was not sure which one is correct.

After many trials I finally skipped most of the previous errors I was getting, and now I'm stuck at trying to set up an Array using a variable from the UserForm.

Here's the code inside Userform

```
VBA
Public Sub TextBox1_Initialize()
    M = TextBox1
    Unload M
End Sub
```

And here's the code inside the module

```
VBA
Public M As Integer

Sub Move()
    Dim XY(M, 0) As Integer
    Object.Move XY
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you `Unload`ing anything? ...in the `Initialize` handler ...of a *textbox*? AFAIK textboxes don't fire any `Initialize` events..

Comment: `Object` is a reserved name in VBA, you can't use it like that AFAIK. Unless CorelDRAW's type library defines something with a global instance named `Object`.

Comment: Assuming `TextBox1` is an actual `TextBox`, delete that `Initialize` "handler" and select `TextBox1` from the left-side dropdown menu (near the top of the code pane); the VBE should create a `_Change` handler for you: that's where you'll want to assign `M = TextBox1.Text`, but word of advice, validate the contents of the textbox before you try to assign an `Integer` with some `String` value.